# Optimizing the select query with multiple similar inner queries

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I have been writing a query on a big single table. I am not at all into the databases. The query looks very big and I feel it can be shortened but don't seem to find a way. I tried using the WITH clause which would have made the query simpler. However, I cannot use that.

Following is the query:

```
 SELECT id, 
       name, 
       Count(name), 
       SUM(event.time_spent_millis), 
       flag, 
       template 
FROM   event 
WHERE  event.host = 'mantis' 
       AND event .` input ` NOT LIKE '%random%' 
       AND id IN (SELECT event1.id 
                  FROM   event AS event1 
                  WHERE  ( event1.host = 'mantis' 
                           AND timestamp BETWEEN 1559337058633 AND 1559683282607 
                           AND template IN ( 'wrap' ) 
                           AND event1.flag = '22' 
                           AND event1.name = 'jack' )) 
        OR id IN (SELECT a.id 
                  FROM   event AS a 
                  WHERE  a .` input ` LIKE '%random%' 
                         AND a.name = 'jack' 
                         AND a.host = 'mantis' 
                         AND template IN ( 'wrap' ) 
                         AND timestamp BETWEEN 1559337058633 AND 1559683282607 
                         AND a.flag IN ( '0', '1' ) 
                         AND a.id NOT IN (SELECT b.id 
                                          FROM   event AS b 
                                          WHERE  b.flag = '22' 
                                                 AND b.host = 'mantis' 
                                                 AND b.timestamp BETWEEN 
                                                     1559337058633 AND 
                                                     1559683282607 
                                                 AND b.name = 'jack')) 
GROUP  BY id, 
          name
```

Sample data:

```
id  name    time    flag    template
aaa123  jack    6561    22  wrap
aaa123  matt    18  NULL    NULL
aaa123  matt1   1126    0   NULL
baa123  jack    6561    22  wrap
baa123  matt    18  NULL    NULL
baa123  matt1   1126    0   NULL
```

To summarize what I want as the result is:

For the given input I want all the name related with the flag and the names associated with that name.

In the given data the output would identify for flag **22**, **jack** has **2** count and **others** has **4** count and time is the sum of all (including jack and others).

The query does not give the desired output because it was getting more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the following code is the optimized version of your SQL using sub-query

```
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       Count(name), 
       SUM(event.time_spent_millis), 
       flag, 
       template 
FROM   event e
WHERE  e.host = 'mantis' 
       e.timestamp BETWEEN 1559337058633 AND 1559683282607 
       AND e.template = 'wrap' 
       AND e.flag = '22' 
       AND e.name = 'jack'
       AND (
         (e .` input ` NOT LIKE '%random%' AND e.flag = '22')
         OR
         (e .` input ` LIKE '%random%' AND e.flag IN ( '0', '1' ))
       )
GROUP  BY e.id, 
          e.name
```

Comment: This is awesome. Not exactly correct but made it work. Will do some testing and get back. Changes I made: where clause goes into a subquery to filter id and the outer flag check removed. Thanks.

Comment: @Jardanian avoid using sub-query if `WHERE` clause do the job. Because sub-query hampers performance. Thanks.

Comment: I need to get the names related to jack for that I need to filter by id and then get other names. I have added the new query in the post.